# ASP.NET MVC can't find my namespace

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm developing a simple blog system and I'm stuck on a position. I want to refer an external library Components, where I have Article class. Trying to set the type of the model in the view `@model Components.Article` I', receiving an error telling me that I'm missing some assembly (I've already refer it in References). Tried to use `@using Components` before the module - same result - `CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Components' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)` Any ideas how can I fix that?

Comment: Are you sure that the `Components.Article` is in that namespace?

Comment: I second @DevEstacion comment. Open project References, double click on the Components library and check the correct namespace in the Object Browser.

Answer (score 2):

Open the web.config file in your Views folder, and make sure it has the following:

```
<system.web.webPages.razor>
        <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
            <namespaces>
                <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
                <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
<add namespace="Your.Namespace.Components" />
            </namespaces>
        </pages>
    </system.web.webPages.razor>
```

Comment: I've just tried it, and it's now throwing me an exception for the View/Home/Index.cshtml

Comment: What does your Exception say?

Comment: It leads me to Views\Blog\Index.cshtml and it saying me that `The type or namespace name Components could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)` and showing me some using that I don't have in any of my project files `Line 29:     using Components;`

Comment: Make sure that you have made above changes in web.config that resides in Views folder

Comment: Make sure you can reference that assembly from server side code. The problem can be related to other dependent libraries of that one.

Answer (score 0):

When you add a folder to your solution and want to make reference to it by @using sometimes you need to Build your solution again so that this error goes away, in other words you need to refresh your solution folders.